# AirPlay working with iPad but rarely with iTunes on my mac?

Tags: airport, airplay

I don't get why, when I play music with AirPlay from my iPad it always work, but with iTunes on my mac it rarely work. It says after 10 seconds:

```
The AirPlay device “My Airport Express” cannot be found on your network.
```

The iPad works perfectly instead.

It worked also on the mac few times (so it should be correctly configured).

thanks

Comment: I suddenly (like in the last month or so) am seeing the exact same issue.

Comment: Have you disabled IPv6 on the Mac or turned on / installed any firewall software?